# Proof involving binomial sums

Tags: summation, proof-writing, binomial-coefficients, neural-networks

I'm reading about [Cover’s Function Counting Theorem](http://www.cns.nyu.edu/~eorhan/notes/covers-theorem.pdf) and I want to prove that when $p/N = 2$ it is true that

$$\frac{C(p,N)}{2^p}=\frac12$$

as is shown in the plot in that same link.

In Hertz, Krogh & Palmer's *Introduction to the Theory of Neural Computation* it is stated that

> It is actually easy to show from the symmetry ${{2n}\choose{n-m}}={{2n}\choose{n+m}}$ of binomial coefficients that $$C(2N,N)=2^{p-1}$$

That's exactly the result I want, as is just another way of writing the equality I wrote at the beginning. In sum, what I want to prove is that

$$2\sum\limits_{i=0}^{N-1}{{2N-1}\choose{i}}\stackrel{?}{=}2^{2N-1}$$

I don't know how to start, because the superior limit of the summation doesn't match the upper index of the binomial coefficient. According to the book I quoted, it appears that at some point the symmetry of binomial coefficients should be used, but I can't come up with any ideas.

Comment: Is $C(p,N)= \binom{p}{N}$

Comment: @JaideepKhare No, in the link the operation $C(p,N)$ is defined. The definition is $C(p,N)=2\sum\limits_{i=0}^{N-1}{{p-1}\choose{i}}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So we would like to prove $$2\sum\limits_{i=0}^{N-1}{{2N-1}\choose{i}}\stackrel{}{=}2^{2N-1}$$
First we know:
$$1.1.\sum\limits_{i=0}^{2N-1}{{2N-1}\choose{i}}=(1+1)^{2N-1}=2^{2N-1}$$
Secondly we know the rule of symmetry of the binomial coefficients
$${{K}\choose{i}}={{K}\choose{K-i}}\implies{{2N-1}\choose{i}}={{2N-1}\choose{2N-1-i}}$$ 
The above sum can be written:$$\sum\limits_{i=0}^{2N-1}{{2N-1}\choose{i}}=\sum\limits_{i=0}^{N-1}{{2N-1}\choose{i}}+{{2N-1}\choose{2N-1-i}}=2\sum\limits_{i=0}^{N-1}{{2N-1}\choose{i}}$$ 
The last equality by the symmetry, and from 1.1 our equality holds.
Q.E.D